# Getting a data from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, axios

```
router.get('/channels', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    channel.find({}, function(err, channeldata) {
        var channelMap = {};
        console.log('channelMap:');
        console.log(channelMap);
        channeldata.forEach((chn)=> {
            console.log(chn)
            var arr = chn
        });

        if(err || channeldata === null){
                res.status(404).send({
                    message: 'Channel Not Found',
                    data: []
                })
        }
        else {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: "channel success",
                    data: arr
                })
        }
        console.log(channelMap);
        // res.send(userMap);  
    });
});
```

here is how I implemented my GET and I am trying the get the `chn` which looks like

[image]

from my DB. Above is the result from `console.log(chn)`

I try to get this by doing

```
axios.get('/channels').then( (res) => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch( (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

in my frontend, but the app crashes and give me an error message saying

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

ReferenceError: arr is not defined
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the lines

```
channeldata.forEach((chn)=> {
            console.log(chn)
            var arr = chn
        });
```

You are defining `arr` in the for each loop, which means `arr` can only be used *inside* the loop.

if you swap `arr` for `chn` in the code

```
res.status(200).json({
                    message: "channel success",
                    data: arr
                })
```

Then that should work